# Chromecast support for youtube videos played via the youtube player API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, chromecast

When I watch videos in the official youtube app on my Android device, I see the familiar cast icon in the toolbar, which sends the playing video to my chromecast.

I want to write my own app that uses the official youtube player API for Android. Playing with the Android samples (https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/sample-applications), I've noticed that the chromecast icon is missing.

What is the best way to add chromecast support to my app which uses YoutubePlayerView or YoutubePlayerFragment to play videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if you want to use chromecast for the YouTube API, then you can start by knowing how to [integrate Cast in an Android App](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender_integrate). You will learn here the basic information that you need to know. Also, check this [YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) to know how it is works.

I found here a [demo](https://github.com/jlmcdonald/yt-chromecast-demo) that shows how to integrate YouTube APIs with Chromecast. It is designed for developers who are learning about the Chromecast SDK or YouTube APIs, or for those wishing to run a code lab on various Google technologies.

Comment: Could you please share your demo link?